# Is there a way to reach printer in this network schema?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

Below there is my network schema, I need to have to networks one for cables and another for wi-fi. The printer is connected to the wi-fi router (192.168.2.1) and the computer is on the cabled router (192.168.1.1). But, the computer (192.168.1.100) cannot find the printer (192.168.2.15). Is there a way to make this possible? Do I need to change some configurations?

[image: Network Schema]

Comment: When you say "cannot find", are you expecting the printer to show up in network discovery, or are you expecting the printer to be reachable by IP address, or both?

Comment: Obviously, telling you the diagram shows a printer that is already reachable doesn’t help you. But it does. So, can you clarify what the problem is and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user1686 I am expecting printer to be reachable by IP address

Comment: @Appleoddity my computer (192.168.1.100) cannot ping or reach the printer (192.168.2.15)

Comment: @Appleoddity by the way, even when I connect a computer on the wifi-router, it cannot ping my cabled desktop

Comment: This isn’t a full picture of your network. For instance, there’s no internet connection. So it’s hard to say exactly what scenario you have here or if any recommendation fits in with your use case. This is essentially a routing question. Each router needs to have, in its routing table, a next hop for the network it doesn’t have direct knowledge of. So, the router at 192.168.1.1 needs to know about 192.168.2.x and vice versa. But if any of these routers are doing network address translation you may not need a route and instead need to use port forwarding on 192.168.2.1.

Comment: In this scenario you should not be using NAT on the two routers, but again I don’t have a complete picture of the network.

Comment: Try this:   Turn OFF wireless Isolation in the wireless router(s).  I also suggest (assuming your picture to be accurate) using just one subnet.